# Google Publisher Tag Roadblocks and Infinite Scroll

Tags: javascript, html, ads, google-publisher-tag

Based on this [infinite scroll example from google](https://support.google.com/admanager/answer/4578089?hl=en#infiniteContents) I tried to build an example with multiple slots for Roadblocks. But it seems the reloaded ads are not initialising correctly. In the end it should work like the [junkee magazine](https://junkee.com/candys-kings-cross-lockout-laws/221513)

My initialising for the Slots:

```
googletag.cmd.push(function() {
    adslotSkyLeft = googletag.defineSlot('/5064286/Skyscraper_Left', [120, 600], 'sky-left-ad').
    setTargeting("test","infinitescroll").
    addService(googletag.pubads());

    adslotSkyRight = googletag.defineSlot('/5064286/Skyscraper_Right', [120, 600], 'sky-right-ad').
    setTargeting("test","infinitescroll").
    addService(googletag.pubads());

    adslotMrec = googletag.defineSlot('/5064286/SideBar_MREC', [300, 250], 'mrec-ad').
    setTargeting("test","infinitescroll").
    addService(googletag.pubads());

    adslotLeader = googletag.defineSlot('/5064286/Leaderboards', [[970, 250], [970, 90], [728, 90]], 'leaderboard-ad').
    setTargeting("test","infinitescroll").
    addService(googletag.pubads());

    googletag.pubads().enableSingleRequest();
    googletag.pubads().disableInitialLoad();
    googletag.enableServices();
});
```

My try to initialise the ads on the reloaded content.

```
googletag.cmd.push(function() {
    var adslotSkyLeftReload = googletag.defineSlot('/5064286/Skyscraper_Left', [120, 600], 'sky-left-ad-' + newId).
    setTargeting("test","infinitescroll").
    addService(googletag.pubads());

    var adslotSkyRightReload = googletag.defineSlot('/5064286/Skyscraper_Right', [120, 600], 'sky-right-ad-' + newId).
    setTargeting("test","infinitescroll").
    addService(googletag.pubads());

    var adslotMrecReload = googletag.defineSlot('/5064286/SideBar_MREC', [300, 250], 'mrec-ad-' + newId).
    setTargeting("test","infinitescroll").
    addService(googletag.pubads());

    var adslotLeaderReload = googletag.defineSlot('/5064286/Leaderboards', [[970, 250], [970, 90], [728, 90]], 'leaderboard-ad-' + newId).
    setTargeting("test","infinitescroll").
    addService(googletag.pubads());

    googletag.pubads().enableSingleRequest();

    googletag.display('sky-left-ad-' + newId);
    googletag.display('sky-right-ad-' + newId);
    googletag.display('mrec-ad-' + newId);
    googletag.display('leaderboard-ad-' + newId);

    googletag.pubads().refresh([adslotSkyLeftReload, adslotSkyRightReload, adslotMrecReload, adslotLeaderReload]);
});
```

As there is more necessary code here my current code: https://jsbin.com/bebabit/edit?output Click the more button at least 6-8 times and you may have to allow third party scripts (GPT JS) to see the ads.

Thank You!

Comment: your current code seems to work. what is the problem ?

Comment: When reloading the content the ads are not filled correctly. Means mismatch of roadblocks, no roadblocks, empty slots and sometimes all of the slots are empty.